# Ajax popup list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, popup, x-editable, magnific-popup, bootstrap-confirmation

I need something like Bootstrap Editable or Bootstrap Confirmation.

But I'm not getting the actual thing that I need.

I need an ajax response when clicked on a button like this,

[image]

Here the text will be loaded through ajax and show the content in the popup.

Please help me, someone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you make it online demo may be will help you.

Comment: @vadivela I need some reference from where I could build it.